# Rails ActiveAdmin before filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to add "is_admin?" filter to ActiveAdmin initializer. In which file should I define the "is_admin?" method?

```
  # == Controller Filters
  #
  # You can add before, after and around filters to all of your
  # Active Admin resources from here. 
  #
  config.before_filter :is_admin?
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your app/controllers/application_controller.rb